# How can i connect my JDBC in java web to XAMPP (localhost) (NETBEANS)?

Tags: java, netbeans, xampp, glassfish

I keep getting the error message saying in glassfish that I have no sqlconnector , i have already added it to to the build path , but it keeps failing any work around to use XAMPP with java NetBeans web application ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution to the error I was facing with the solution is below:

1. Download the mysql-connector.jar which is compatible with
   glassfish and NetBeans you are using
2. Go to glassfish/lib and paste the jar
3. Go to glassfish/domain1(the domain you are using)/lib -> paste
   the jar there

4.The work is done and ready to use, I solved the issue with this.